# css flex почему не работает flex-basis?

Tags: css3, flexbox

Почти победила я в неравной борьбе с адаптивным меню картинками на flex. 
Но при проверке адаптивности с шагом 10 px вижу, что одна проблема осталась. На разрешениях от width 1488 до 1840 px и от 1841 до 2193 px смещение происходит некорректно.

Нужный результат - это смещение на 2-ю строку сразу трех блоков меню из шести. То есть, там, где не помещаются все 6 блоков, они должны выстраиваться в 2 строки по 3 блока в каждой. Именно это не получается. Дальше по 2 блока в строке и по 1 уже нормально выстраиваются

Попыталась задать блоку-обертке ширину на проблемных `@media screen`.

И ничего у меня не получилось. Не работает `flex-basis`? Или я его криво задаю?

А вот кусок html, к которому я хочу все это применить:

```css
/** Стили для меню картинками **/

.container {
  all: initial;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.choice {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url(Plan.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-content-between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  inherit: none;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1488) {
  .container {
    flex-basis: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100) {
  .container {
    flex-basis: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="wrapper d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap">
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/database.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Последнее обновление</a></h3><br />
        <img src='Today-final.jpg' alt='Все квартиры за сегодня' />
        <figcaption>Адреса и описания / Все варианты за сегодня</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/area.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3 class="select"><a href=''>По районам СПб</a></h3><br />
        <img src='Metro-distr-final.jpg' alt='Квартиры по районам и метро'>
        <figcaption>Длительная аренда по районам и метро</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/sut.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Посуточные квартиры</a></h3><br />
        <img src='Sutochno-final.jpg' alt='Аренда на несколько дней'>
        <figcaption>
          Квартиры в аренду на короткие сроки</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>

    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/database.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Однокомнатные квартиры</a></h3><br />
        <img src='1KKV-final.jpg' alt='Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб' />
        <figcaption>Снять однокомнатную квартиру в СПб</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/area.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Двухкомнатные квартиры</a></h3><br />
        <img src='2KKV-final.jpg' alt='Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб'>
        <figcaption>Снять двухкомнатную квартиру в СПб
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="choice" onclick="location.href='http://www.сайт.ru/sut.html';">
      <figure>
        <h3><a href=''>Трехкомнатные квартиры и более</a></h3><br />
        <img src='3KKV-final.jpg' alt='Снять трех-, четырехкомнатную квартиру в СПб'>
        <figcaption>
          Снять трехкомнатную, четырехкомнатную ...</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Уже перепробовала очень много всего. И здесь мне помогали решить проблему. Но в общем коде страницы мне не помогли даже весьма дельные советы, которые работали без вставки в мой код.

Вижу решение в задании flex-basis. Ан, не получается. Опять :((
Поправьте, дрУги, где я ошибаюсь? Я флекс только начала изучать :(

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "некорректно"? Обьясните, какой результат вы хотите получить и что не получается у вас.

Comment: Нажмите "Выполнить код" - "На всю страницу". И при постепенном уменьшении размеров окна Вы увидите, что неправильно. То самое "некорректное" смещение. А нужный результат - это смещение на 2-ю строку сразу трех блоков меню из шести. То есть, там, где не помещаются все 6 блоков, они должны выстраиваться в 2 строки по 3 блока в каждой. Именно это не получается. Дальше по 2 блока в строке и по 1 уже нормально выстраиваются.

Comment: flex-basis задается флекс элементу внутри флекс контейнера, это величина за которую будет бороться элемент до того момента пока ему хватает места. В вашем случае вам нужно, либо обернуть ваши элементы по 3 в отдельные дивы, либо задавать ширину например в 33% тогда элементов будет по 3 в каждой строке... Еще можно добавить какой-то элемент по середине, который разделит ваши блоки.

Comment: Спасибо. Завтра попробую так сделать. Отпишусь, что получилось

Comment: @Наталья, тогда стоит сдлеать как написал @l2banners . Задать блокам 33% при нужном размере экрана.
P.S. Насколько я помню вы используете `section` не правильно, в `nav` он не нужен.

Comment: @E_K Там скорее nav не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, друзья! Общими усилиями (+ перелопатив здесь же другие подобные вопросы) решила вопрос так (БЕЗ ВСЯКИХ `flex-basis`):

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: center;
}
.container { 
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 1430px) {
    .container {
        width: 60%; 
        inherit: none;
    }
}
```

Может, что-то лишнее или неправильное. Но работает именно так, как нужно, на любых разрешениях и в любых браузерах. Даже на IE.
ВОПРОС ЗАКРЫТ